# How to create or alter a DB schema dynamically (at run time) using Gramex FormHandler

Tags: database, schema, gramex

I want to be able to (at run time) create or alter a DB schema dynamically on a particular event (e.g. click of a button) using FormHandler microservice of Gramex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormHandler supports [defining columns in the spec](https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/formhandler/#formhandler-columns).

For example, this configuration creates a table called `profile` with 4 columns: user, password, age and id.

```yaml
url:
    handler: FormHandler
    kwargs:
      url: 'postgresql://$USER:$PASS@server/db'       # Pick any database
      table: profile              # Pick any table name to create
      id: id                      # The "id" column is primary key
      # Define your table's columns
      columns:
        user: TEXT                # Use any SQL type allowed by DB
        password: VARCHAR(40)     # including customizations
        age:
          type: INTEGER           # You can also specify as a dict
          nullable: true          # Allows NULL values for this field
          default: 0              # that default to zero
        id:
          type: INTEGER           # Define an integer ID column
          primary_key: true       # as a primary key
          autoincrement: true     # that auto-increments
```

But if this needs to be changed at runtime, e.g. when a user clicks on a button, you can use a [FunctionHandler](https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/functionhandler/) with [`gramex.data.alter()`](https://learn.gramener.com/gramex/gramex.html#gramex.data.alter)

For example, add this to your `gramex.yaml`:

```yaml
url:
  alter:
    pattern: /alter
    handler: FunctionHandler
    kwargs:
      # You can decide the columns dynamically here
      function: >
        gramex.data.alter(url, table, columns={
           col: 'TEXT' for col in handler.args.get('col', [])
        })
```

When `/alter?col=email` is called, the function adds an `email` column as text.

NOTE: There's no option to DELETE columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using queryfunction of FormHandler which can modify the query based on the query parameters passed in the url.

Refer the link below for more
https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/formhandler/#formhandler-queryfunction

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

In your yaml handler:

`queryfunction: mymodule.sales_query(args)`

In your python code:

```
def sales_query(args):
    cities = args.get('ct', [])
    if len(cities) > 0:
        vals = ', '.join("'%s'" % pymysql.escape_string(v) for v in cities)
        return 'SELECT * FROM sales WHERE city IN (%s)' % vals
    else:
        return 'SELECT * FROM sales'
```

Reference from:
https://gramener.com/gramex/guide/formhandler/#formhandler-queryfunction